# How to check if there is a new line or not at the end of ifstream file. (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, input, newline, ifstream

I have a program that works perfectly if there is a `\n` at the end of `ifstream` file.

The task was like this:
Define the structure of the product 
( product name , category , price , quantity in stock ) .
From File trgovina.txt ( It may already contain predefined products. "Like in the picture i posted) 
Through functions :

1. 1 load the products in to array from an existing file tgovina.txt
2. 2 Allow the product name printing from the file proizvodi.txt ( every product in new line )
3. enable search of products by category 
   ( load the category from the user and prints out the names of products and categories on the screen and into the file which is named as "the required category" )
4. Enable printing of product which are less than 10 in stock in the file lessthen10.txt
5. Allow printing the most expensive and the cheapest products on display
6. Allow the entry of new products into the database ( write it to a file trgovina.txt )

The problem starts [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeQkT.png): if the person stops writing at the first yellow marker, I would like to add a new line, so that when I want to add a new text, it will start in new line. If there is already a new line at the end of the text file, I want to just continue writing without adding new line.

The second problem is if the ofstream file has no text: in that case, I don't want to add a new line.

```
ofstream dat("trgovina.txt", std::ios_base::app);
if (!dat)
{
  cout << "Mistake!" << endl;
  return;
}
string name;
string category;
bool a = true;
double price;
int quantity;
while (a)
{   
  **//Here I want to check if there is a "\n" sign at the end of text
    //if there isn't I want to add one, and then continue writing.
    // But if the text file was empty i dont want to add new line**

  cout << "enter the name of new product: ";
  getline(cin, name);
  dat << name << "|";
  cout << "enter the category of new product: ";
  getline(cin, category);
  dat << category << "|";
  cout << "enter the price of new product: ";
  cin >> price;
  dat << price << "|";
  cout << "enter the quantity of new product: ";
  cin >> quantity;
  dat << quantity << endl; **//This works if the txt file is empty or if 
                             //there is "\n" at the end**
  cout << "more? (1 / 0)";
  cin >> a;
  cin.ignore();
  system("cls");
};
dat.close();
```

Sorry for my bad english.

I got an error using

```
while (a)
{   
    trgovina.seekg(-1); 
    char c;
    trgovina.get(c);
    if (c == '\n')
    {

    }
    else
    {
        dat << endl;
    }
```

This is the picture[image: Picture] of the txt file after running few new lines from this code. It put's a new line on the top if the file was empty, if not it works good.

Comment: You have prompts and `getlines` in your code snippet, indicating interactive input, but you're reading from a text file where multiple portions of data are in the same line. This is most likely incorrect. You want to read in each field one at a time, or read a line and parse the fields from it. `getline` will fail when end of input is reached. If there is an empty line, you will read an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Its an `ofstream` so a stream in which you can only write. What you need is both reading (to determine what's inside) and write (to add items), this is called an `fstream`. You can read, write and seek into a `fstream`. To determine if the last char of it is a newline, just seek to the last char and read it with something like that:

```
fstream f("myfile.txt",std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
f.seekg(-1,is.f.end); // move the the end
char c;
f.get(c);
if (c=='\n') ...
else         ...
```

Comment: `seekg` calls `filebuf::seekoff`, which in turn is defined in terms of the C function `fseek`. Accordingly the only valid position when using `end` is `0` for a file opened in text mode. That isn't to say your code won't work most if not all of the time, but an implementation would be perfectly free to even ignore the seek, or seek to the end rather than the last character.

Comment: 27.8.2.4 // 10 *If (newoff + off) < 0* means that values could be negative, *the function assigns xbeg + newoff + off to the next pointer xnext* is the calculation. Almost the same for fseek.

Comment: [filebuf.virtuals] `seekoff` calls `fseek`.  `int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence);`: For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the `ftell` function on a stream associated with the same file and `whence` shall be `SEEK_SET`.